Difference between batch size and train batch size and validation batch size
The finetuning job creation required us to specify the values for these three kinds of batch sizes in the Azure ML Studio but I do not understand why we are specifying the batch size initially if we have to provide the values for the training and validation batch sizes.
Batch size
Train and Val batch size
I have tried scanning through the docs online but none of them address this (to my knowledge).

The batch size (batch_size) is the number of training examples used to train a single forward and backward pass.
In the same line, the validation batch size represents the number of examples for the validation batch.
The reference manual gives some clear guidance on this topic - https://www.linkedin.com/in/jaganadhg/
